# Python: list index out of range - while/for loop

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
abc = ['date1','sentence1','date2','sentence2'...]
```

I want to do sentiment analysis on the sentences. After that I want to store the results in a list that looks like:

```
xyz =[['date1','sentence1','sentiment1'],['date2','sentence2','sentiment2']...]
```

For this I have tried following code:

```
def result(doc):
    x = 2
    i = 3
    for lijn in doc:
        sentiment = classifier.classify(word_feats_test(doc[i]))
        xyz.extend(([doc[x],doc[i],sentiment])
        x = x + 2
        i = i + 2
```

The len(abc) is about 7500. I start out with x as 2 and i as 3, as I don't want to use the first two elements of the list.

I keep on getting the error 'list index out of range', no matter what I try (while, for loops...)

Can anybody help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Are `x = x + 2; i = i + 2` _inside_ your loop?

Comment: @yole I'm trying to reproduce what I did, but now I'm not getting any output at all. It is as if Python is going through an "infinite loop".

Comment: @ForceBru yes they are, I edited it in my original post

Comment: Looks like you've missed ")" char on the 6th line of your "result" function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
i =0
for i in xrange(0,len(doc) -1)
    date = doc[i]
    sentence = doc[i + 1]
    sentiment = classifier.classify(word_feats_test(sentence))
    xyz.append([date,sentence,classifier])
```

Only need one index. The important thing is knowing when to stop.

Also, check out the difference between extend and append

Finally I would suggest you store your data as a list of dictionaries rather than a list of lists. That lets you access the items by field name rather than index , which makes for cleaner code.

Comment: Could someone be a dear and indent the append. Having trouble getting it to indent on mobile...

Answer (score 1):

As comments mentioned - we won't be able to help You with finding error in Your code without stacktrace. But it is easy to solve Your problem like this:

```
xyz = []
def result(abc):
    for item in xrange(0, len(abc), 2): # replace xrange with range in python3
        #sentiment = classifier.classify(word_feats_test(abc[item]))
        sentiment = "sentiment" + str(1 + (item + 1) / 2) 
        xyz.append([abc[item], abc[item + 1], sentiment])
```

You might want to read about [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) functions that makes programmers life easy. (Why worry about incrementing if range has that already?)

```
#output
[['date1', 'sentence1', 'sentiment1'],
 ['date2', 'sentence2', 'sentiment2'],
 ['date3', 'sentence3', 'sentiment3'],
 ['date4', 'sentence4', 'sentiment4'],
 ['date5', 'sentence5', 'sentiment5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two elements from your list at a time, you can use a generator then pass the element/s to your classifier:

```
abc = ["ignore","ignore",'date1','sentence1','date2','sentence2']

from itertools import islice


def iter_doc(doc, skip=False):
    it = iter(doc)
    if skip: # if  skip is set, start from index doc[skip:]
         it = iter(islice(it, skip, None))
    date, sent = next(it), next(it)
    while date and sent:
        yield date, sent
        date, sent = next(it, ""), next(it, "")


for d, sen in result(abc, 2): # skip set to to so we ignore first two elements
    print(d, sen)

date1 sentence1
date2 sentence2
```

So to create you list of lists xyz you can use a list comprehension:

```
xyz = [ [d,sen,classifier.classify(word_feats_test(sen))] for d, sen in iter_doc(abc, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. you can try it:

```
>>> abc = ['date1','sentence1','date2','sentence2'...]    
>>> xyz = [[ abc[i], abc[i+1], "sentiment"+ str(i/2 + 1)] for i in range(0, len(abc), 2) ]
>>> xyz
output : [['date1', 'sentence1', 'sentiment1'], ['date2', 'sentence2', 'sentiment2'], .....]
```